# Get users credits for the last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to make a bar chart with the progression of the users credits amount. I store the credits change in a table with two columns, old_amount and new_amount. It also has a column called time_added.

I thought if I could grab the last one on the day and get the new_amount it would give me the credit count the user had on that day.

```
$playersCredits7daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCredits6daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCredits5daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCredits4daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCredits3daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCredits2daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCreditsYesterday = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->orderBy('time_added', 'DESC')->take(1)->new_amount;
$playersCreditsToday = $player->credits;
```

As you can see my query almost works, how would I do a where clause to ensure it falls within the day I need it to? and doesn't select one from a different day?

I store the time it was added in a column called time_added in this format: `2017-03-04 21:05:58`

Comment: We cannot see your query almost works. :P I mean, it may not have any syntax errors, results at runtime is a different beast.

Comment: My query works fine because it runs perfectly fine. I'm just asking for help with the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eloquent `whereDate` method

```
$playersCredits7daysAgo = CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->whereDate('time_added', Carbon::today()->subDays(7))->first()->new_amount;
```

or if you want to do in one query

```
CashChanges::where('user_id', $player->id)->where('time_added', '>', Carbon::today()->subDays(7))->pluck('new_amount', 'time_added');
```

this will return array of `new_amount` and `time_added` as key